# Dealing with RAW + jpg collections in Darktable: I only want to export processed RAW

Tags: raw, darktable, export

If I have a bunch of pictures transferred from a camera, where the camera was set up to do RAW+jpg, I can click the "G" button in Darktable to "group" the RAW and JPEG images together in the "lighttable" view. However, when one image is selected in that situation, Darktable (2.6) says that I've got **2** images selected; I have to assume that means both the RAW and the JPEG file. When I do an export of one file, I get indications that it's exporting 2 files as promised. I only need one of course.

This may be some new behavior with 2.6; I'm not sure.

Of course I only want to export the RAW file as affected by the various edits I've applied; exporting the JPEG version is not valuable, and of course if it happens *after* the RAW is exported it's a serious negative.

So is there some way to tell it that I only want to work on the RAW companion to a pair of images?

Comment: This does indeed sound like new behavior in 2.6. I've been doing that for ages and I only got one exported image per selected file.

Comment: @qwazix it's odd; I'm really pretty darn sure that it didn't do that previously, and the fact that it actually does seem to do two actual exports (based on what it logs to the terminal) seems pointless anyway. I have not fiddled with preferences; I just fired it up and looked at some old directories full of images. If I un-click the "G" option and then just click on a raw file, then that seems to count as just one image. Note that the redundant export is to the same filename (I have the "overwrite" option checked in the export tool).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This seems to be [intended behavior](https://redmine.darktable.org/issues/8968#note-34) in Darktable 2.6

Actually treating the *group* as a selection of two photos makes sense in most cases (Rating, Deletion, Move etc). However the good developers of DT knew that [every change breaks someone's workflow](https://xkcd.com/1172/) so they added a new collection option named **group leaders** that allows the user to access the old behavior.

[image: screenshot of the new collection option in darktable]

Comment: I don't disagree that there's some sense to selecting both images of a group, at least in some cases, but for purposes of _exporting_ the files, particularly with the "Overwrite" mode of the export tool, it seems pretty questionable. But if I can turn it off, I'm happy. Thank you so much!

Comment: Maybe I don't know how to use the "collect images" interface very well, but going into "grouping" mode seems pretty cumbersome; I generally organize photographs by shoot (usually just date), so I don't know how I'd use that to tell it I want to not pay attention to camera JPG files for some individual film roll (or, probably what I'd prefer, always). I'll keep reading.

Comment: I'm thinking that because of what I currently do with my photos mostly involves the raw files, I should just not bother with the JPG versions (in Darktable) since I really almost never look at them. Again, thanks for steering me to that additional information!

Comment: If you don't want to bother with `jpg` files at all you can ignore them while importing (problem solved). I do want to keep the jpegs for photos I don't particularly like, or want to edit. Regarding the collection interface you can ask another question if you'd like a better explanation but in short you collect your images as you like (choose your preferred film roll) and then press the down arrow on the right and choose *narrow down search*. Then choose grouping.

Comment: I'll start playing with it now. Darktable's UI is a little weird and my first experiences made me think it was designed by crazy people but I've mostly gotten really fond of it. Again, thanks!

Comment: Oh durr I get it now; it's all a database and that's a query interface. Mind expanded.